# Exporting PDF from Google Drive doc - File name loses all spaces

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, pdf

We use Google Drive to create documents, and when we publish / release them we export them as a `.pdf` by using the inbuilt `File > Download as > PDF Document (pdf)`. But when we get the PDF file the spaces have been lost from the title.

So a file that has the title set in Google Drive like this:

> My list 2013

will be exported as:

```
Mylist2013.pdf
```

I would prefer it to be formatted as:

```
My list 2013.pdf
```

Any ideas how I can correct this so it would use that format (without manually correcting it when its on my local machine)?

Comment: Not all OSes do well with spaces in filenames. I'd think that a filename without spaces would be the safer choice. That said, there does not appear to be a way for you to change how Google Drive names "download as" files.

Comment: Thanks @AlEverett - just as an example do you know which OSes dont like spaces in file names ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://cloudconvert.org/

[image]

The nice thing about this cloud service is that you can grant it access to your Google Drive and select the items that you want to convert. It will then convert them and pop them back in your Google Drive. You get 25 free conversion a day.

I have just tested it and uses the original file name.

There is also an API available should you wish to build something yourself. This is just one small part of the service they offer - there are many more conversion options available.

Comment: But does it leave the file name intact?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra Yes it does, `I have just tested it and uses the original file name.`

Answer (score 1):

Ive found an odd work arround to this, although it only works when downloading multiple files, not singular ones, if your in the Google Drive dashboard, mark the files you want to donwload then go to `more > download > pdf > click download` this will now download you a zip folder containing all the files you selected, when you unzip that folder you'll notice the pdf's it contains leave the spaces in tack in their titles.

Although this is an awfully long way to achieve the spaces, if you just want one file your better off downloading it as a pdf and manually replacing the spaces in the title.